# Why does the F-117 Nighthawk look different than other stealth planes?

Tags: aircraft-design, stealth, f-117

The [F-117 Nighthawk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_F-117_Nighthawk) has flat angled lines where most later designs (B2, F22, F35) have very smooth lines. Why the difference? Are the newer designs 'more stealth'? Do they use a different design to handle better? Is there another reason the distinct angled look is avoided in later designs?

The question, '[Why do many stealth aircraft have a similar shape and design?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/45532)', is close, but doesn't really address why the F-117 stands out from the rest.

[image]
Left: [F-117](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:F-117_Nighthawk_Front.jpg), right: [F-22](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Two_F-22A_Raptor_in_column_flight_-_(Noise_reduced).jpg).

Comment: I can recommend the book [Skunk Works: A Personal Memoir of My Years of Lockheed](https://books.google.fi/books/about/Skunk_Works.html?id=nXUbFuRT9LwC) where Ben Rich explains the history and testing of the Have Blue project and the final F-117.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Initial work on Radar Cross Section (RCS) reduction concentrated on absorbers and had started in Germany late in WW II. The Americans were not interested at the time, but British scientists documented the results and gained early insights in US RCS research when they pooled their results in the 1970s.

Lockheed started work on the systematical reduction of RCS when they discovered the academic papers of [Petr Ufimtsev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petr_Ufimtsev), a Russian mathematician who explained how to calculate the reflection of radio waves from the 1960s on. Their initial success with RCS reduction on the SR-71 was more luck than systematic work. At the same time, similar insights were gained in Germany where a [manned prototype of an aircraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MBB_Lampyridae) (MBB Lampyridae) similar to the [Have Blue prototype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_Have_Blue) proceeded up to wind tunnel tests. Then the program came to the attention of US authorities which quickly put an end to it.

In all those cases, the major idea was to restrict the surface to large, flat panels because the edges, not the total area, determine how much energy is radiated back. In that respect, the German design was much cleaner than both the Have Blue and the F-117, but I digress. Those designs can be called first-generation stealth aircraft.

When Northrop joined the RCS work, they found that even curved panels work well - after all, it is edge reduction and [alignment](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1798/do-similar-angles-on-a-plane-make-it-more-stealthy) which reduces RCS most. Their initial prototype was for a battlefield observation aircraft (in contrast to the Lockheed attack aircraft) which was called [Tacit Blue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northrop_Tacit_Blue).

When work on stealth prototypes was opened at the end of the Cold War, all engineers could pool their knowledge and combine the work on absorbers, edge reduction and edge alignment. This gave rise to the second generation of stealth designs which look indeed quite different to those of the first generation. What also influenced the designs was more understanding of the tactical value of stealth, so the second generation designs do not optimize RCS above all else but arrive at a compromise which [combines low frontal RCS with good agility](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/36026/why-do-the-f-22-and-f-35-look-similar-to-each-other-and-different-from-previous/36031#36031) and multi-role capabilities.

Koyovis is right, but it was not only computer power but also the limitations of early RCS codes which were based - at least in case of Lockheed - on the ideas of Petr Ufimtsev, and he in turn used analytical methods which did not allow to investigate the RCS of curved surfaces. However, the computers at the time were already powerful enough to allow the F-117 to fly at all - in contrast to the MBB design, it is unstable and uncontrollable without artificial stabilization.

Comment: While studying aerospace engineering in university, I hypothesized that one could trace everything in our curriculum back to Germany, and apparently that holds true for stealth technology too. Very cool :)

Comment: @techSultan: Well, if you ask the Russians, they will tell you that all comes from [Russian pioneers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Mozhaysky). And Ufimtsev really did pioneering work.

Comment: My understanding was that the paint on more recent aircraft significantly contributes to RCS reduction beyond what can be achieved with geometric considerations and modifications. Would that contribution help alleviate the need optimizing edge geometry etc.?

Comment: @nodapic: No. Absorbing paint was among the first techniques used, so it is not restricted to more recent designs. The absorbers are frequency-specific, so they work only for/against some radar systems. For edge alignment they are no replacement, but they help for example to reduce backscatter in intakes.

Answer (score 40):

The reason I had heard, and seems to be confirmed by [this site](http://www.boldmethod.com/blog/lists/2014/09/f-117-little-known-facts-nighthawk/), is that the computers at the time of design were not powerful enough to compute radar reflection off of curved surfaces.

[image]

The photo is from the same site - it sure looks like something only a 70s computer could love. It most definitely makes aerodynamicists weep.

Comment: That certainly makes sense if that is the answer. It does look like something from an early video game!

Comment: That is also the answer I always heard , however that is not really a proof of it’s validity either.

Comment: A parallel development in Germany has a similar design feel to it. This might very well be due to the limitations of computing power at the time https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MBB_Lampyridae

Comment: @rul30 it is indeed the reason. It was mentioned in several books about the ATF competition that led to the F-22 which I read. The available computer power dictated that only flat surface reflections could be calculated in reasonable time, so that's what they ended up with.

Comment: It was more the limitations of the algorithms than of computer power. Early algorithms were based on analytical work which used no computers at all.

Comment: "It most definitely makes aerodynamicists weep." It probably made flight simulator makers happy, though!

Comment: Stealth ships seem to have somewhat similar design: https://www.google.de/search?q=stealth+ships&rlz=1C5CHFA_enDE730DE731&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiuntDG2OHYAhVhD5oKHdN8CegQ_AUICigB&biw=1680&bih=930

Comment: Reflection difficult to compute? Hum this is to be confirmed, as I recall early versions of [POV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POV-Ray) ray tracing, that worked not so bad on personal computers.

Comment: @mins: remember we are talking about the 1970s and its not ray tracing but diffraction of electromagnetic waves.

Comment: @mins- My father played a multi-player, wire-frame graphics flight sim/air combat game (who's name I've long since forgotten) on the mainframe system available at the University of Illinois in the mid-70s (74-75ish). While I'm sure it wasn't as realistic as current flight-sims, ahem, it was pretty darn good. So yeah, computing power back then wasn't as bad as we like to think it was. Of course, every (literal) bit of memory was accounted for as was each CPU instruction...

Comment: @mins, raytracing is the wrong tool for dealing with radar waves.  As far as I know, nobody's ever managed to get electromagnetic radiation below about the terahertz frequencies to show particle-like behavior, so you need to use far-more-complicated wavefront simulation techniques.

Comment: @Mark particle-like behaviour is irrelevant to whether raytracing is an appropriate tool. For example, it is a perfectly useful technique in seismology, although the energy quanta of earthquake waves ([phonons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonon)) are way, _way_ to low for to ever exhibit particle-like behaviour. The real reason raytracing isn't sufficient for RCS is that radar wavelengths aren't that much smaller than the size scales of a plane. — Besides, even if it's tricky to show directly in experiments, it's almost completely certain that radar EMR _is_ quantified as photons.

Comment: @rul30: Diffraction is a solved problem in ray tracing, and ray tracing itself can be seen as a statisticial approximation of electromagnetic wave simulation. Ray tracing's not just Whitted Style Toy Ray Tracing, but goes much, much further (the terms Monte Carlo experiments, Markov chains, Metropolis sampling, Photometry and Radiometry and more are just a random sample of what is part of modern [i.e. since the 90s] ray tracing)

Comment: @phresnel: interesting it did not know that, [let's get into that](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/381013/can-ray-tracing-be-used-to-design-a-stealth-air-craft-or-is-it-necessary-to-use?noredirect=1#comment853962_381013).

Comment: @FreeMan: Sounds like [PLATO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PLATO_(computer_system)). It was awesome for the time.

Comment: @JamesKPolk yes, that was it! Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @rul30: Great question. I am not actually sure if ray tracing is appropriate for modelling stealth devices or for wave modelling in general.

Comment: Battlezone! That head-on shot of the F-117 looks like a screen grab from the 1980 Atari console game [Battlezone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battlezone_(1980_video_game)). Here's a link to an [image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8a/Bradley_Trainer_screenshot.png) from when the Army adapted the game to train their gunners in the Bradly Fighting Vehicle.