# Why don’t gliders use swallow tails?

Tags: glider, empennage

I’ve always wondered this. Why do gliders use a T-style tail, as opposed to a V-tail ie a swallow tail design?  I think it would represent a significant reduction in weight over a conventional empennage, not to mention, offering a reduction in drag.

Comment: Because the swallows needed them and would not give them up :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The V-tail was a trend in glider design between the late Fifties and the early Sixties. High-performance gliders like the [HKS-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HKS-1), the [Arlington Sisu 1A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sisu_1A)$^*$, the [SB-5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaflieg_Braunschweig_SB-5_Danzig), the [Standard Austria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schempp-Hirth_Standard_Austria) or the [Schempp-Hirth SHK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schempp-Hirth_SHK) had them, as well as the aerobatic [H-101 Salto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Start_%2B_Flug_H-101).

However, eventually the T-tail became the preferred choice for these reasons:

- The endplate effect of the horizontal allows to make the vertical about 20% smaller.
- A T-tail will suffer the least damage in an outside landing.
- The [effectiveness of a V-tail is lower](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9504/what-is-the-difference-between-the-v-shape-tail-and-the-straight-tail-on-the-bee/9509#9509) for the same area, especially in damping.
- V-tails are [not really better](http://www.wwiiaircraftperformance.org/me109/me109g-14003.html) in terms of drag reduction.

$^*$ Added thanks to the helpful advice by Thomas Perry.

Comment: A friend had an Austria glider with unusually large all-flying V tail surfaces and anti-servo tabs. He said it was actually deficient in rudder authority, making it a challenge in x winds.

Comment: @JohnK Name me one glider which isn't deficient in rudder authority at low speed. They all are, more or less. Fly fast enough and things become fine, though.

Comment: @PeterKämpf  ...and I am going to add, the enigmatic Sisu 1A, if that is ok with you...

Comment: @ThomasPerry: Thank you, that is a very welcome addition!

Comment: @PeterKämpf  Thank you, Peter.  Your acknowledgement is very kind.

Comment: @ThomasPerry ... and well deserved. I had no prior knowledge of the Sisu 1A.